# Share image in iMessage using Custom Keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, emoji, ios-app-extension

I am working on iOS 8 custom keyboard, where i have designed keyboard using some images like smiley. i want this keyboard to be work with iMessage. when i am trying to send text its working properly but can't able to share image there. I have tried following code :

**To share text : (its working properly)**

```
-(void)shouldAddCharector:(NSString*)Charector{
    if ([Charector isEqualToString:@"Clear"]) {
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
    } else if([Charector isEqualToString:@"Dismiss"]){
        [self dismissKeyboard];
    } else {
        [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:Charector];
    }
}
```

**To add image : ( Not working)**

```
-(void)shouldAddImage:(UIImage*)oneImage
{
        UIImage* onions = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];

        NSMutableAttributedString *mas;
        NSTextAttachment* onionatt = [NSTextAttachment new];
        onionatt.image = onions;
        onionatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0,-5,onions.size.width,onions.size.height);
        NSAttributedString* onionattchar = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:onionatt];

        NSRange r = [[mas string] rangeOfString:@"Onions"];
        [mas insertAttributedString:onionattchar atIndex:(r.location + r.length)];
        NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mas];
        [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:string];
}
```

Is there any possibility to pass image to `[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:string];`

following attached image shows how exactly i want to use this image keyboard. i am surprised how emoji keyboard will work? [image]

Comment: is there anyway to convert my attributedstring(image) to NSString format so i can atatch images...

Comment: @Gaurav: did you find anything on this?

Comment: @Manthan I have done in a way that matt suggested below. You can check performance by downloading hi-art app from appstore.

Comment: Follow this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426098/ios-custom-keyboard-i-want-to-send-images-to-the-textdocumentproxyinput-contr

Comment: Do you have any solution for this @Gaurav, Please help me with the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

**As far as I know, the behavior you are looking for is not possible as of iOS 8 beta 4**.

Currently, the only way for iOS custom keyboards to interact with text is through `<UITextDocumentProxy>` and the only way to insert *anything* is via the `insertText:` method.

Here is the header for the `insertText:` method in `<UITextDocumentProxy>`:

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text;
```

As you can see, it takes a plain `NSString`... not an `NSAttributedString`. This is why your attempt to insert an image doesn't work.

However, despite the fact that you can't add pictures, it is still very possible to insert emojis, since an emoticon is really just a Unicode character.

To add an emoji, just insert the proper Unicode character:

```
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\U0001F603"];
```

**Useful links:**

***List of Unicode Emoji***: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

***Unicode Characters as NSStrings***: [Writing a unicode character with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101644/writing-a-unicode-character-with-nsstring)

Comment: Thanks matt, i have already done with emoji adding to keyboard now just looking for a workaround to add image.

Comment: There is no work around. Unfortunately, it's simply not possible.

Comment: is there anyway to convert my attributedstring(image) to NSString format so i can atatch images.

Comment: Only way to achieve this is copy that image to clipboard and user will manually paste it.

Comment: Has this feature been added yet?  iOS 8.3 is out, can we do this now?

Comment: @Matt: Then how to do something similar like this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rage-faces-keyboard/id924790727?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: It works by placing the image on the user's clipboard, and requires the user to paste it in, as Gaurav said above.  Many custom keyboards with images are being implemented in this way, and as of iOS 8.3, there is still no better way to do it.  **Please be sure to file a feature request with Apple via the bug reporter.**

Comment: What about the Viber, Facebook and other apps? copy pasting is just a hack. Any idea?