# IOS getting libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting error when trying to use pasteboard method to post images through input control of the custom keyboard I am following this tutorial [question]: [iOS: Custom keyboard: I want to send images to the textDocumentProxy(Input controls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426098/ios-custom-keyboard-i-want-to-send-images-to-the-textdocumentproxyinput-contr) , but I am getting error when trying to send the image with above error of the title that I stated I really hoped some of you guys can help me out.

```
-(void)keyBoardButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender

    {

    //    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

        if (sender.tag==1111) {
            [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"⒜⒝⒞⒟Ψ"];
            NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(@"apple.png");

            if(imgData == nil){
                NSLog(@"error image");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"true image");
            }


            NSLog(@"pressed 1");

        }
```

Comment: Show the whole error message, there should be more about the NSException. But `UIImagePNGRepresentation();` expects a `UIImage`  object as parameter, not a `NSString`.

Comment: you mean UIImagePNGRepresentation() I should change to UIImage?

Comment: Hi @Larme u there?

Comment: The official Doc `NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image);`. The doc as you are coding it : `NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation(NSString *imageName);` (which is invented). So `NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"]);` maybe? And you still didn't post more about that crash log you got about that NSException.

Comment: Thanks @Larme it works you are the best!

Comment: Didn't Xcode throw a warning `"Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'UIImage * _Nonnull'"` for that line?

Comment: No it didnt....

Comment: Hi @Larme one more thing after adding the image file apple.png in my file I got nsexception error again can I know what is wrong again?

Comment: Again, give the complete error message!

Comment: damn it it works already thanks btw for your help